# default fabric8 microservice errors out on integration test - Waiting for container:spring-boot. Reason:CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: fabric8

Deployed fabric8 in Google Container Engine with 12 core 45GB RAM. Used gofabric8 0.4.69 for deploying fabric8 on GCE.

Tried to create a microservice, but it is failing in integration testing phase throwing the following error "Waiting for container:spring-boot. Reason:CrashLoopBackOff"

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Which quickstart were you trying?

It sounds like the application terminated. I wonder if this shows any output:

```
kubectl get pod
kubectl logs nameofpod
```

where `nameofpod` is the pod that is crashing.

BTW the new fabric8-maven-plugin version (3.1.45 or later) now has a nicer [fabric8:run](https://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:run) goal.

If you clone the git repository to your local file system and update the version of fabric8-maven-plugin you should be able to run it via:

```
mvn fabric8:run
```

Then you get to see the output of the spring app in your console to see if something fails etc.

Comment: I've recreated the problem and it has now been fixed.  There was an issue with the base image used to build the new app.  Unfortunately whilst testing I found another issue which means until that's fixed the pipeline will continue to fail.  Details can be tracked here https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/6358 we should have a release out soon to fix.